# How can I decrease the number on a button?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to create a GUI that has only one button. Each time the button is pressed the number on the button should decrease. So I wrote this:

```
import Tkinter

def countdown(x):        
   x -= 1

top = Tkinter.Tk()

def helloCallBack():    
    countdown(x)    

B = Tkinter.Button(top, text=x, command=helloCallBack )   
B.pack()       
top.mainloop()
```

I want that button's text to be like 5 4 3 2 1, so where should I put the `x=5`?

Comment: Why did you undo that edit? Was it not incredibly obvious you were making it much less readable?

Comment: did i just undo it ? oh god my bad i thought it was a suggestion and tried to make it better coppied it and created that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create global variable and use it in function `countdown` (but you have to use `global`) and then you can use `config(text=...)` to change text on button.

```
import Tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def countdown():
    global x # use global variable

    x -= 1

    B.config(text=x)

# --- main ---

# create global variable (can be in any place - before/after function, before/after Tk())
x = 5

top = tk.Tk()

B = tk.Button(top, text=x, command=countdown)   
B.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

Or you can use `IntVar()` and `textvariable` - so you don't need `config(text=...)` and `global`.

```
import Tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def countdown():
    x.set( x.get()-1 )

# --- main ---

top = tk.Tk()

# create global variable (have to be after Tk())
x = tk.IntVar()
x.set(5)

# use `textvariable` and `lambda` to run `countdown` with `x`
B = tk.Button(top, textvariable=x, command=countdown)   
B.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

I use `lambda` to run `countdown()` with `x` so I can use `countdown` with many buttons with different `IntVar`. (you can't do the same in first example when you use `int`)

```
import Tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def countdown(var):
    var.set( var.get()-1 )

# --- main ---

top = tk.Tk()

# create global variable (have to be after Tk())
x = tk.IntVar()
x.set(5)

y = tk.IntVar()
y.set(5)

# use `textvariable` and `lambda` to run `countdown` with `x`
B1 = tk.Button(top, textvariable=x, command=lambda:countdown(x))   
B1.pack()

B2 = tk.Button(top, textvariable=y, command=lambda:countdown(y))   
B2.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

---

BTW: you can use `after(miliseconds, functio_name)` to run function `countdown` every 1s and countdown without clicking :)

```
import Tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def countdown(var):
    var.set( var.get()-1 )

    # run again time after 1000ms (1s)
    top.after(1000, lambda:countdown(var))

# --- main ---

top = tk.Tk()

# create global variable (have to be after Tk())
x = tk.IntVar()
x.set(5)

# use `textvariable` and `lambda` to run `countdown` with `x`
B = tk.Button(top, textvariable=x)   
B.pack()

# run first time after 1000ms (1s)
top.after(1000, lambda:countdown(x))

top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

As described in the "Button" section of http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/control-variables.html, you need to create a special `StringVar` to make the button dynamically update. You can pass the `StringVar` into the `textvariable` variable of the `Button` constructor and update the `StringVar` value inside the `countdown()` function. http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/button.html states that `textvariable` is

> An instance of StringVar() that is associated with the text on this button. If the variable is changed, the new value will be displayed on the button.

Comment: `StringVar()` is overkill for this. You can just do `B.config(text=..)`